# How to reduce size and size on disk?

Tags: katalon-studio

We have created Automation Projects using Katalon Studio..

Currently The project folder size is it shows like:

Size: 1.61 MB
Size on Disk: 4.45 MB
Contains: 1033 Files, 444 Folders

How to reduce the difference between Size and Size on Disk.. When project grows is it needs to be sorted out?

Comment: are you really worried about an extra 3MB? Filesystems these days use defaults that speed up access at the expense of a little wasted space. This is usually a good trade off because storage is really cheap.

Comment: This is on going project. Need lot of automation codes pending. That's worried item

Comment: I don't think this overhead here will scale linearly with the size of the project, its probably just disproportionately large relative to content because there isn't much content yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably related to your disk [cluster size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_cluster). Files can be no smaller than the cluster size, which is usually somewhere in the range of a few KB. For example, if your cluster size is 4KB then a 1 byte file will still take up 4KB on the disk. Generally this is more noticeable when you have many small files. If you want to change this you will need to reformat your filesystem and choose a smaller cluster size.